# How do I configure webdrivermanger to selectively call Tor or Firefox on demand (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tor, webdrivermanager-python

sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm trying to figure out how to use Selenium to control Tor browser (which i understand is modified Firefox), but I can't find any instructions on how to do it on a system that also has regular Firefox and other browsers installed.
I am using the following code but when the *webdriver.Firefox()* starts it *opens a new non tor Firefox window*, ending up with Tor Browser and Firefox running simultaneously, with Firefox indicating it under "remote control" not Tor.

**How do I configure *webdrivermanger* to selectively call Tor or Firefox on demand?**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
import os

torexe = os.popen(r"/usr/bin/flatpak run com.github.micahflee.torbrowser-launcher")

profile = FirefoxProfile(r'/home/khan/.var/app/com.github.micahflee.torbrowser-launcher/data/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
profile.update_preferences()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("http://google.com")
```

PS: I'm on Linux Mint 21